# Control in html5 VIDEO changing a layout

Tags: html, video

I have a small problem with HTML5 video element.

Without "Controls" it has a border-radius, as I set it.
[image]

But, when I add control (and I need it) - it gives me this ugly border and didn't see border-radius what I set. Maybe someone know how I can reach this "control" and change it as well? 
Or maybe we have some rules for this?

[image]

You asked for a code, here you go:

```
<div class="header__video">
   <video src="images/our.mp4" controls type="video/mp4" autoplay="false" preload="none">

   </video>
</div>

video{
    height: 30rem;
    border-radius: 50px;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
}
```

`.header__video` - just a flex container.

Comment: please add some of your code

Comment: @SASSY_ROG added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that difficult, just add another container around it, set it's `border-radius` to `50px` and it's `overflow: hidden`

```html
<div class="header__video">
   <div class="video-container">
       <video src="images/our.mp4" controls="controls" type="video/mp4" autoplay="false" preload="none"></video>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
video {
    height: 30rem;
    outline: none;
}

.video-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Man, you're right.

I tried to add the container itself too, but I put overflow:hidden to a video itself... don't know why.
Thanks, man.